# Validate text area for input numeric, comma, dot and space not allowed

Tags: javascript, validation, restriction

I have placed one text box and I want to put restriction on it .

Only number,comma,dot can be allowed to input in text area and space not be allowed.

Comment: This question doesn't show an attempt at solving the problem. Where is your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might face this problem in a lot of different ways. Most people would propably just strip the users input after he had finished typing. But heres my attept I did a few years ago (uses [prototype.js](/questions/tagged/prototype.js), but should be easily rewritten):

```
Element.prototype.watchInput = function(data){
    if(Object.isString(data))
        data = {allow:data};

    var data = Object.extend({
        letters: true,
        numbers: true,
        allow: '_'
     }, data || { });

     $(this).observe('keypress', function(e){
        setTimeout(function(){
            var elem = $(Event.element(e));
            var value = elem.getValue();
            var input = value.substr(value.length-1).toLowerCase(); // last character
            var replace = '';

            var remove = true;
            if(data.letters && 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.include(input)) remove = false;
            if(data.numbers && '01234567890'.include(input)) remove = false;
            if(data.allow && data.allow.include(input)) remove = false;

            if(remove){
                elem.setValue(value.gsub(input, replace));
            }
        }, 3);
    });
    return this;
}
```

Use this by simply applying it to your input/textarea:

```
$('myInput').watchInput({letters:false,allow:',.'});
```

The element will be observed on any `keypress`. Since the keypress event does not receive the clients input directly, we have to wait a bit (in my case 3 millisec).
After that, we validate the last charakter of the clients input and remove it in case it is invalid.

*I know, this isn't the most beautiful code, but I think the idea is worth spreading.*

---

[Here is a preview](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/rHnqg/) of the setup above.

Comment: Why you want framework prototype.js you can done with just javascript

Comment: Yes you are right. Feel free to edit the answer my friend :)